# Timer event in powershell not working in remote session

Tags: powershell

I have a remote PowerShell session from machine A to B. Requirement is to do a continuous check inside B. On a specific condition, I have to execute something and stop the timer. For that, I created a timer function. But that timer function is not starting.

The code that I have written is:

```
$timer = new-object timers.timer 

$action = {
    write-host "inside loop.."
    # Condition to check comes here.
}

$timer.Enabled = $true 
$timer.Interval = 3000 #3 seconds 

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier thetimer -Action $action 

$timer.start()
```

I expect the output to be

> inside loop..
>       inside loop..
>       inside loop..

but the actual output is:

> Id----------------1
>   Name--------------thetimer
>   PSJobTypeName----------
>   State-------------NotStarted
>   HasMoreData-------False

Comment: How are you invoking the remote command?

Comment: @boxdog It is invoked from a web-service like `String command = "powershell.exe " + "$password = ConvertTo-SecureString '" + targetPassword + "' -AsPlainText -Force;" + "$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentList '" + targetLogin + "',$password;" + "$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName " + targetComputerName + " -Credential $cred;" + "Enter-PSSession $session;" + "Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath " + script + " -ArgumentList " + params + ";";`

Comment: Please put the code into the Question instead of a comment, it's hard to read.